# Indexing and Crawling using nutch with solr

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch, full-text-indexing

Am newbie to nutch and solr, I trying to index and crawl a single website using Nutch with solr but am getting this error., I don't know what is the exact error. can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance.

```
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20181011155036.
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20181011155140.
Indexer: starting at 2018-10-11 15:54:06
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
No exchange was configured. The documents will be routed to all index writers.
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    type : Type of the server. Can be: "cloud", "concurrent", "http" or "lb"
    url : URL of the SOLR instance or URL of the Zookeeper quorum
    commitSize : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    auth : use authentication (default false)
    username : username for authentication
    password : password for authentication


Indexing 20/20 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:152enter code here)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:244)
```

Comment: You need to configure index-writers.xml into nutch conf folder with your collection URL.
`<param name="url" value="http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE-NAME"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, Index has been succeeded but now i got this No exchange was configured. The documents will be routed to all index writers.
No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

Comment: Did you find an answer to the problem? @Vinodkumar